# invariant measure on a quotient of a topological group

Tags: group-theory, measure-theory, lie-groups, topological-groups

Suppose I have a locally compact topological group, $G$, and a closed subgroup $H\leq G$. Suppose $\Delta _G|_H = \Delta_H$ where the $\Delta$ are the modular functions on $G$ and $H$. How can I see that there is a $G$-invariant Borel measure on $G/H$ which is unique up to constant coefficient?

Comment: I'm not sure why this is being closed. It's a fine question.

Comment: See also https://mathoverflow.net/questions/14278/haar-measure-on-a-quotient-references-for

Comment: Specifically, the reference Nachbin, L. _The Haar integral_ (1965): page 138 Theorem 1.

Answer (score 1):

See Theorem 1.5.2 in Deitmar and Echterhoff's [Prinicples of Harmonic Analysis](http://books.google.co.jp/books?id=BMcpBAAAQBAJ).

Comment: That is Theorem 1.5.3, I think.